# why does the instance have no attribute?

Tags: python

```
class Test():    
       myVersion="1.0" 
t=Test()   
t.myVersion    
--> 1.0

Test.myVersion="2.0"  
Test.x={'myVersion':'1.0'}
Test.x  
--> {'myVersion': '1.0'}

t.x 
--> {'myVersion': '1.0'}

del t.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute 'x'
```

Why has the instance t no attribute `x`?
{'myVersion': '1.0'}  is not  the attribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, both `class` and `instance` attributes are accessible from an instance.

Ref `Class instances` in http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html clarifies how this works -

> A class instance is created by calling a class object (see above). A
>   class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes.

You can see your class and instance's namespace using `Test.__dict__` and `t.__dict__` respectively.

Interestingly, if you modify a class attribute by referencing it from the instance, the class attribute will remain unaffected. Instead, a copy of the attribute with the change will be added to the instance's namespace.

For example,

```
>>> t = Test()  
>>> t.myVersion = "2.0"  
>>> Test.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', 'myversion': '1.0', '__doc__': None}
>>> t.__dict__
{'myVersion': '2.0'}
```

`myVersion` attribute is now present in both `Test` (class) and `t` (instance)'s namespace, and can be safely deleted from either without raising an `AttributeError`.

The basic idea is that a variable you are trying to delete from an object should be present in its namespace.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the variable isn't attached to the instance, it's attached to **the whole class.** To fix this, you have to physically attach it (ok, maybe not *physically*, but you get what I mean) to the instance.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myVersion = '1.0'
```

Then you can delete it.

```
t = Test()
del t.myVersion  # no exception raised
```